# End editing when clicking on another UITextView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have an UITableViewController with several customs cells, each of then containing a single UITextView. I would like that, if the user is being editing cell A and then clicks on cell B, cell A ends editing but cell B *does not* begin editing.

Right now I have the following gesture recognizer that ends the editing of a cell when clicking outside the tableView :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

But when clicking on another UITextView this textview calls `shouldBeginEditing`afterwards and hence this get ignored.

I tried playing with the `textViewShouldBeginEditing` / `textViewShouldEndEditing`functions but had no success. I don't know whether I should pursue this direction or create another gesture recognizer with a custom associated action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of things that you need to setup to get this to work.

All your `UITextField` would need to have their delegate set. You need to keep track whether a `UITextField` is currently being edited or not. If so, you need to call `resignFirstResponder` otherwise you will let your newly tapped `UITextField` start editing.

Code would look something like this.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
{
    if self.currentTextField == nil 
    {
      self.currentTextField = textField
      return true 
    } 
    else 
    {
      self.currentTextField!.resignFirstResponder()
      self.currentTextField = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I as looking for! I think it is better to put the `resignFirstResponder` part in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` part (for the case where the user taps outside of the tableView).